# Why bother to use Memory warning event methods?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

If my app uses less than 10MB do I have to bother to use those methods? I know that they are for caching low memory situations but this might occur only if you do not tested you app before releasing it. If you have tested your app, the app does not have leaks, have a small memory footprint, then why should anyone bother to use memory warning methods?

Comment: Because your application might be running with a bunch of other apps and everyone is using memory, if you can release unnecessary memory your app will run faster even with all the others using too much memory. That's also good citizenship, your app is only using as much memory as it really needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Your app is probably not the only thing running on the device.** Other apps and processes are also taking up memory, and in some situations they may need it more than you. It's always a good idea to respond to memory warnings by releasing cached data that can easily be loaded again. That way the operating system has control over the memory usage, and it won't have to terminate your app.

Comment: Further to this argument, in an instance where another app needs memory you're holding and could release, but you fail to do so, your app will be killed. So responding properly to memory warnings means your app will remain in memory more often, giving your users a better experience and making them think you did a better job.